# Python implementation of Quadtree for trajectory analysis

Tags: python, hpc

I am working on a trajectory analysis project using python and its data science related libraries. I am planning to implement Quadtrees for for trajectory analysis, each trajectory has sequence of (x,y) coordinates along with timestamp, speed, dist between consecutive points, etc.

I would kindly request if anyone who has experience with quadtrees and trajectory analysis, can provide with some useful links for Python implementation of quadtree. I would not ask that implementation should be focussed on trajectory analysis but should be able to provide an idea for the same. My ultimate goal is to cluster the similar trajectories (location and direction wise).

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`scipy.spatial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/spatial.html). It has an implementation of a [KD-tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), which should work fine for your application.